# How to update values in Javascript array based on another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Not sure what's going on but can only guess its some weird reference issue rather than a copy. I have two arrays. One has an orderIndex I would like to update the sorted array values with.

This is somehow making all the orderIndexes the first value (in this example 2). Anyone have any idea what is going on?

```js
const array = [{
  orderIndex: 2,
  name: "blah"
}, {
  orderIndex: 1,
  name: "blah"
}, {
  orderIndex: 3,
  name: "blah"
}]


function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.orderIndex < b.orderIndex) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.orderIndex > b.orderIndex) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

// I make a sorted array
tempArray = [...array]

// this sorts the array based on orderIndex
tempArray.sort(compare)

// I then loop through and update the original array
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i].orderIndex = tempArray[i].orderIndex
}
```

Comment: I made a snippet for you. Please make it a [mcve]

Comment: Is it that `orderIndex` is something like `priority` or it is at which `index` that array item must appear. 
If it is a `priority` then `array.sort((a, b)=>a.orderIndex - b.orderIndex);` will work or if denotes index where they should appear then `const newArray = []; for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {newArray[array[i].orderIndex] = array[i];}` second will leave empty space(holes) in array if some index is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference issue at play here is that `[...array]` is making a shallow copy, rather than a deep copy. Thus `array` and `tempArray` both contain pointers to the same objects in memory, thus when you run `array[i].orderIndex = tempArray[i].orderIndex`, you are actually mutating the objects in both arrays.

Few solutions to this:

Make a deep copy, using say lodash:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
tempArray = _.cloneDeep(array)
```

Sort the array inplace:

```
array = _.sortBy(array, 'orderIndex')
```

Or else store the sorting of orderIndex as an array of primitives, before attempting to mutate

```
orderIndexes = [...array].sort(compare).map(object => object.orderIndex)
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i].orderIndex = orderIndexes[i]
}
```

Comment: Beautiful - this is exactly what was happening. Thanks! 
I did have to use a different lodash command for the copy: cloneDeep. Maybe they updated it in new versions.

Comment: Opps! (fixed) `_.cloneDeep()` is the correct lodash function. I've been spending far too long in python land where the equivalent function is `deepcopy()`

Answer (score 0):

You get a new array qith the original objects for sorting. Instead, you could get a real copy without reference to the original objects by spreading the objects and map these objects.

```js
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.orderIndex < b.orderIndex) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.orderIndex > b.orderIndex) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

var array = [{ orderIndex: 2, name: 'blah2' }, { orderIndex: 1, name: 'blah1' }, { orderIndex: 3, name: 'blah3' }],
    tempArray = array.map(o => ({ ...o }));

tempArray.sort(compare);

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].orderIndex = tempArray[i].orderIndex;
}

console.log(array);
```

A more simplified approach takes only the indices for sorting.

```js
var array = [{ orderIndex: 2, name: 'blah2' }, { orderIndex: 1, name: 'blah1' }, { orderIndex: 3, name: 'blah3' }],
    tempArray = array.map(({ orderIndex }) => orderIndex);

tempArray.sort((a, b) => a - b);

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].orderIndex = tempArray[i];
}

console.log(array);
```